# Cannot reduce array inside of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope, reduce

I am trying to reduce an array inside of an object.  I am getting back

```
push is not a function
```

I have started my array as empty and created a add function to pass in as the first argument.

```
function add(a,b) {
        return a +b;
}

var navBarArray = [];
var listArray = [];

var mapping = {
  ".navbar": navBarArray,
  ".list-group": listArray
};
```

I tried this approach on the mapping object but it creates errors

```
var mapping = {
  ".navbar": Math.round(navBarArray.reduce(add,0) ),
  ".list-group": listArray
};
```

However, I get push is not a function back in my console.

Below is my function that passes values to the array.  I can create a variable inside the function and reduce it there.  However, that limits access to my variable and will bloat my function as I continue.

```
  Object.keys(mapping).forEach(function(selector) { 
      $(selector).hover(function(evt) {
        console.log('mapping',mapping);
        console.log('selector',selector);
        enteredTime = new Date();
      }, function() {
        var ctime = new Date();
        var time = (ctime.getTime() - enteredTime.getTime())/1000;
        mapping[selector].push(time);

        // *********** this works but not where I need it to*******
        var reduce = Math.round(navBarArray.reduce(add,0) );
        console.log(reduce);
        });
    })
```

Comment: Maybe `mapping[selector]` is `undefined`...?

Comment: Which line is getting the error? Calling `reduce` shouldn't report an error about `push`.

Comment: Maybe make sure that `mapping[selector]` is `typeof` `"array"`?

Comment: Result of `reduce` is not an array in your case. And it's not clear what you want it to be actually.

Comment: Matias  I am getting back all of the values inside of the array.  Here is my console      mapping Object {.navbar: Array[5], .list-group: Array[0]}

Comment: The second `var mapping = ...` snippet sets the value of the `.navbar` key to a number, but then you try to use it like an array with `mapping[selector].push(...)`. I think you just need to stick with the first definition of `mapping`.

Comment: @andersschuller .  I agree I was just showing that example to show my thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your mapping object so it has separate places for the array and total:

```
var mapping = {
    ".navbar": {
        total: 0,
        times: []
    },
    ".list-group": {
        total: 0,
        times: []
    }
}
```

Then you do `mapping[selector].times.push(time)`, and put the total with:

```
mapping[selector].total = mapping[selector].times.reduce(add, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I follow this approach.  From what I read I could not place a reduce in the object.

Comment: You must have misread or misunderstood. There's nothing special about `reduce`, it's just a function call that returns a value. And you can put any value in an object.